# Explorer Hidden Taskbar Breaks

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

On my Windows 7 PC, I have the taskbar set to auto-hide and all works fine except for a few occasions when it well get stuck up and nothing I can do will hide it again. Not even re-setting the auto-hide.

There is one work around I have and that's opening Command Prompt and typing in `taskkill /f /im explorer.exe` then `explorer.exe`. That reloads explorer completely and fixes the problem.

My question is, is there way to stop this from happening or at least an easier way to fix this? It hasn't happened often enough for me to consider writing a batch script but it's getting to the point where I might.

**EDIT:** Ending up writing the batch script anyway (only works in Windows 7 afaik).

```
@echo off
cls
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe >nul
timeout 1 /nobreak >nul
explorer.exe
exit
```

Still would like possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article [Fixing When the Windows Taskbar Refuses to Auto-Hide Correctly](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/31779/fixing-when-the-windows-taskbar-refuses-to-auto-hide-correctly/)
describes this problem as :

> When you’re using the auto-hide feature for the Windows taskbar, it
>   will stay hidden until an application starts flashing the taskbar
>   button, or there’s a notification balloon from a system tray icon.
>
> In
>   the first case I can simply click on that window to dismiss the
>   notification and the taskbar will hide again.
>
> The other scenario is when a notification balloon pops up, which will
>   cause the taskbar to stay visible until you dismiss the message. These
>   are obviously easy to close as well, or you can [customize the
>   notifications to not display](http://blogs.howtogeek.com/mysticgeek/2009/04/21/how-to-manage-action-center-in-windows-7/).
>
> The problem, however, is that some applications are not written quite
>   right, and they trigger a notification in Windows to keep the taskbar
>   open, but don’t display anything visible for you to close. This
>   problem is even worse when combined with Windows 7’s ability to hide
>   system tray icons.

The steps the article advises to take are :

1. Verify the Taskbar Settings
2. Open up the hidden icons and right-click on them to identify the misbehaving application
3. Customize the notification settings to change
   the icon that is hidden from the default of "Hide icon and notifications" to "Only show notifications"

Other possible solutions :

1. Restart Windows Explorer (as you have done)
2. Completely [disable balloon notifications](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-all-notification-balloons-in-windows-vista/) via regedit in
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
   create a new 32-bit DWORD named `EnableBalloonTips` and the value of 0
3. Use the Solve PC Issues icon in the system tray, which is just part of the Action Center. Sometimes clicking on the icon to open up the Action Center and view the messages will fix the issue.
4. Other issues, for instance the Outlook reminders window, will keep the taskbar open. You will need to turn off such alerts ([example for Outlook 2010](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22282/turn-off-desktop-email-alerts-in-outlook-2010/)).